# How does memory gets allocated for string literal in c and do we need to free it?

Tags: c, string

How does memory gets allocated for a string literal in C and do we need to free it?
E.g.:

```
char *k="hello world";
```

Where does this string get stored and how does it get de-allocated?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1704407/3194340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where does this string get stored

Usually in read-only memory, you cannot modify it. In `gcc`, on most systems, they are located in the `.TEXT` section.

> how does it get de-allocated

upon program termination.